# Stuck on old gui?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, kali-linux, gui

- Kali Linux
- 2021.3

I had been using the updated xfce GUI, the one released in 2020/21 I believe then when I was playing around with linux I must've messed it up because I believe I have reverted to the old GUI. I tried `sudo apt upgrade` and rebooted my pc to no avail. Is there a possible fix to revert to the old GUI ? I am rather new to linux so forgive me if I'm just being stupid but thanks !

Comment: If you're new to linux, you are using the WRONG distro. Kali is intended for expert use. Try Ubuntu, Mint, MX linux, those are user friendly. Once you learn more you'll understand why Kali is not intended to be used in the way you are trying to use it. Just because Mr. Robot, whose character is an expert hacker/cracker, used kali sometimes, doesn't mean that's a good idea for most users.

Comment: @Lizardx Also, using Kali won't make one a "hacker", it's the other way around. "Hackers" (penetration testing experts) will choose Kali as a specialized tool for their job, since that's what it is.

Comment: Never said I wanted to be a hacker man just enjoy pen-testing in general, also maybe but I find the best way I learn is throwing myself in the deep-end and forcing myself to learn, and until now I haven't really had much issue. :)

Comment: Vilinkameni, yes, that's my point exactly, the endless stream of users who break their kali installs because they got the whole thing backwards. Sassan, if you want to learn, use a better platform, run a decent stable distribution and learn how to install the testing tools on them, then you'll actually learn something and have a nice stable system as well, from which you can productively learn more. distros don't do penetration testing, tools do it, so learn the tools and focus on them, not the distro, which isn't meant to be used the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

The old look is typically caused by the desktop environment or theme. You could try the [official FAQ on switching to the new default - Xfce](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/xfce-faq/#switch-desktop-environments):

> **Q**: I absolutely love the new theme and I desperately want it, but without having to re-install my system. How can I migrate my existing Kali Linux installation?
>
> **A**: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y kali-desktop-xfce` in a terminal session to install the new Kali Linux Xfce environment. When asked to select the “Default display manager”, choose `lightdm`.
>
> Next, run `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` and select Xfce’s option. If you would also like to remove the Gnome window manager, which we do not recommend until you are sure you are ready to, run `apt purge --autoremove kali-desktop-gnome`. Be sure to run this *after* setting up Xfce.
>
> Next time you login after a reboot you will have the Xfce theme, if you did not run the `update-alternatives` command you can choose “Xfce” in the session selector in the top right hand corner of the login screen.
>
> **Q**: I installed Xfce, but it doesn’t look like the preview. How can I get it to look the same?
>
> **A**: If you are having issues, it may be that a config file is not set properly. First, backup .cache, .config, and .local. Next, running `rm -r .cache .config .local` and then rebooting will likely fix those issues.

As a new GNU/Linux user, make sure you've considered the official guidance on choosing Kali Linux: [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)

> … if you are looking for a Linux distribution to use as a learning tool to get to know your way around Linux, or if you want a distro that you can use as a general purpose desktop installation, *Kali Linux is probably not what you are looking for*.